Why is “where $HOME” showing as not found?
When I type where $HOME in terminal I get the following error:
/Users/juliapak not found

echo $HOME seems to work, but why do I have hidden files?
juliapak@julias-MacBook-Air ~ % where $HOME
/Users/juliapak not found
juliapak@julias-MacBook-Air ~ % ls -aleO@ /Users
total 16
drwxrwxrwx   6 root      admin  sunlnk  192  6 Oct 07:14 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root      wheel  sunlnk  640  1 Oct 00:10 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 502       admin  hidden 6148  6 Oct 01:17 .DS_Store
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root      admin  -         0  1 Oct 00:10 .localized
drwxrwxrwx   9 root      admin  -       288  7 Oct 18:00 Shared
drwxr-xr-x  28 juliapak  admin  -       896  7 Oct 18:09 juliapak
juliapak@julias-MacBook-Air ~ % echo $HOME
/Users/juliapak
juliapak@julias-MacBook-Air ~ % echo $HOME
/Users/juliapak


You're using the wrong command (where). I'm not sure what the right command is, because I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it's clear that where is not it. The where command (in zsh) is used to look up commands (like ls, echo, or even where itself), but your home directory is not a command, so it's "not found" as a command.

In othere words: If you had an application located at /Users/juliapak then "where" would tell you where it is. But there is no application at that location, your home directory is there, something completely different.

yeah I figured it out..I was having issues with my ruby gems the other day and kinda went down rabbit hole. Had myself confused. Took me a few hours to fix my gem install path, but I got it done!

See here for what the .localized file is for. .DS_Store contains Finder's settings for the folder (e.g. icon or list view).

where is a csh command to look for a command/binary within PATH. For bash, it's not defined. For zsh, where is the same as whence -ca. From man zshbuiltins:
whence [ -vcwfpamsS ] [ -x num ] name ...
    For each name, indicate how it would be interpreted if used as a command name.
    -a  Do a search for all occurrences of name throughout the command path.
        Normally only the first occurrence is printed.
    -c  Print the results in a csh-like format.

Using where with a directory (as you do with where $HOME) doesn't work as a directoy isn't a command.

Thank you! You are very helpful. Luckily I got this all sorted out on my own last night. Was having issues with my ruby gems the other day and kinda went down rabbit hole. Had myself confused. Took me a few hours to fix my gem install path, but I got it done!
